# Change Image on click (6 Image Loop)

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have 6 images that I want to swap between by clicking on the image but I can't seem to get the code right in order to make it go to the next picture

**HTML**

```
    <img src="BCover.jpg" id="ImgGallery" onclick="ImgGallery()"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var counter = 1;

ImgGallery.onclick = function (){
if (counter == 1){
    document.getElementById("ImgGallery").src = "BCover.jpg";
    counter++;
}
else if (counter == 2){
    document.getElementById("ImgGallery").src = "MechGP.jpg";
    counter++;
}
else if (counter == 3){
    document.getElementById("ImgGallery").src = "Mech2.jpg";
    counter++;
}
else if (counter == 4){
    document.getElementById("ImgGallery").src = "Mech3.jpg";
    counter++;
}
else if (counter == 5){
    document.getElementById("ImgGallery").src = "Mech4.jpg";
    counter++;
}
else if (counter == 6){
    document.getElementById("ImgGallery").src = "MCA1.png";
    counter==1;
}
};
```

Comment: Note assignment is `=`. Also what's not working in this code, any errors? There is an easier way to do this, but after fixing the `==`. [It seems to work without problems](http://jsfiddle.net/caxw4vrc/).

Comment: When I click on an image, it does not swap to the next image.

Comment: Yes it does, look at the fiddle. Note that you want to change `ImgGallery` to `document.getElementById("ImgGallery")` as just  `ImgGallery` will not work in all broswers.

Comment: The fiddle works but when I try to run it through my HTML editor, on my page the picture still doesn't cycle when I run it on Google Chrome :S

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? I'm running on Chrome and it works fine through the fiddle example also. It could be where you are defining the HTML and JS. Mine showing your HTML structure?

Comment: The error that pops up on my console says "Reference Error: rotateGallery is not defined.

Comment: Then the problem is happening somewhere else in your code, as there isn't any call to or definition of `rotateGallery` in the code you posted.

Comment: Where would I put the declaration code of `rotateGallery` then?

Comment: It would be with the rest of your JavaScript, something along the lines of `function rotateGallery(){ /* CodeHere */ }`. *Note* you will want to show the relevant code causing problems in the question.

Comment: Got it working, thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (other than Spencer's comment about == assignment) seems to be that `ImgGallery` should be the name of a function, not a reference to the element, as it's being called as a function in the `onclick` attribute of your img element.

I renamed the `ImgGallery()` function to `rotateGallery` to eliminate ambiguity with the id of the element.

I also took some liberty to clean up your code a little by using array cycling instead of a switch statement to handle img gallery rotation.

```
<img src="BCover.jpg" id="ImgGallery" onclick="rotateGallery()"/>


var counter = 0,
    gallery = ["BCover.jpg", "MechGP.jpg", "Mech2.jpg", "Mech3.jpg", "Mech4.jpg", "MCA1.png"],
    rotateGallery = function () {
        document.getElementById("ImgGallery").src = gallery[counter];
        counter++;
        if (counter >= gallery.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    };
```

Comment: *"ImgGallery should be the name of a function, as it's being referenced in the onclick"* - Actually it's (can be) referencing the element with the **id** `ImgGallery `.

Comment: But he already created an `onclick` attribute in the element.  So his intention seems to be to define a function for rotating the images.

Comment: I agree, it's possible that the OP unknowing setup a working `onclick` for their element.

Answer (score 1):

This can be DRYed up a bit. You can include all of your images in an array. JavaScript does not have a native `cycle` method but you can implement it with the following algorithm.

```
var images = ["BCover.jpg", "MechGP.jpg", "Mech2.jpg", "Mech3.jpg", "Mech4.jpg", "MCA1.png"];
var gallery = document.getElementById("ImgGallery");
var index = 0;

gallery.addEventListener("click", function() {
    gallery.src = images[index];
    index = (index === images.length - 1) ? 0 : index + 1;
});
```

I know the last statement inside the `click` listener may seem weird, but I wanted to write as little code as possible.

Comment: Nice answer.  Looks eerily familiar.  "ImgGallery" needs a capital "i".

Comment: This is a common algorithm to solve the `array#cycle` problem. But yes, we both had the same idea. And thanks for pointing out the spelling mistake. I didn't catch that

Answer (score 0):

ImageGallery isn't a function, which will cause an error.

However, the main error is `counter==1;`, on the third last line. The `==` operator is for testing if a value has equal value (not necessarily equal type though), but for assignment, use the normal `=` operator.
Try this:

```js
//First, create an array of images (so you can support as many images in the gallery as needed, only needing to update this array)
var images = ["BCover.jpg", "MechGP.jpg", "Mech2.jpg", "Mech3.jpg", "Mech4.jpg", "MCA1.png"],
    //and a counter to loop through
    c = 0;

//this function is triggered when the image is clicked on sending the image element as a parameter
function nextImg(elem){
  //if c is less than the array's length - 1, then add 1 to c, otherwise make c equal 0
  c = (c != images.length - 1) ? c + 1 : 0;
  //actually change the src attribute of the image
  elem.src = images[c];
  //and just let you know what image you're up to
  document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = 'Image no. '+(c+1)+'. File name of image: '+images[c];
}
```

```css
/* Make the image visible */
img{
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img id='ImageGallery' onclick='nextImg(this)' />
<p>Notice the onclick attribute</p>
```

Comment: *ImageGallery is undefined* isn't true, in this case it references the element with the **id** `ImageGallery `.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek It is undefined. I'm referencing line 3 in the code provided.

Comment: Most browsers (and modern browsers) will interpret `ImageGallery` as a reference to the element with the id or name of `ImageGallery` if not directly defined in JavaScript.

Comment: Didn't see the need for a downvote, so I reversed it. The code looked legit to me

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I've updated it to your high standards

Comment: @Tobsta Not really high standards, it's just that's not what the problem is. Otherwise the fiddle I've provided in the OP comments would not be working. Your answer is correct, but the reason why the OP's code didn't work would be misinforming the reader.